# kotlin inverse boolean safe casting

Tags: kotlin, null-check, kotlin-null-safety

Let's say I have an object Response. Now I would like to check a boolean variable, success, under Response and do an early return is response is not successful.

```
if(response == null || !response.success){
   return;
} //Java version
```

Now I would like to use Kotlin's null safety check like following

```
if(response?.success ?: true){
    return
}
```

If I'm not wrong, if either response or success is null we'll return true inside the if condition. However, if response.success is not null and equals to true, we will still return from the function, which is not what I want . How do I correct this condition ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to do

```
if(!(response?.success ?: false)){
    return // null or failed
}
```

which is equivalent to your java version.

**but note: if the `null` check version is easier to read. You can use that in Kotlin too**

you can also flip the condition

```
response?.success?.let {
  // do something when success
}
```

[see the Elvis operator doc for more info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)

Comment: I think you are very correct in saying that explicate null check version is so much easier to read.

Comment: I tried to put ! in the front, however, the compiler complains about only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Boolean?

Comment: @Yao I edited my answer. i'm not convinced that it's readable. the problem is `response?.success` has a type `Boolean?` but the ! operator only works with `Boolean`

Comment: @pt2121 Thanks for your reply. I agree with you that this expression is less readable. I think I'm posting this question just to understand what are my options if I am dealing with kotlin safety check.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but I just stumbled over it.
The following may be the shortest if clause:

```
if (response?.success != true) {
   //There is either no response, or it was not successful
}
```